# Javascript get Element

Tags: javascript, css, element

I need some help. I have written a javascript that check out the URL and if the url equals example.com then the script should change the height and the margin of a div element.
It works but it keeps reloading the site all the time and I can't click on anything.

Also how can I get a class? `getElementsByClassName` doesnt work.

```
function verschieben() {
    if (window.location.href = "example.com") {
        document.getElementById('bigimg').style.height = "200px";
        document.getElementById('searchbox').style.marginTop = "30px";
    }
}

verschieben();
```

Comment: `if (window.location.href == "example.com")`

Comment: in if condition it should be == instaed of =

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` will return an array like object so you need to loop trough it or get the correct index. Can you create a Fiddle or something, because this bit of code alone will not make your site break I think.

Comment: `=` is assignment while `===` is comparison. You should really brush up your knowledge on basic JS operators before going into manipulating DOM.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get host information of current page then `window.location.host` will have that value, `href` will contain full url

```
if (window.location.host.toString() == "example.com")
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code for class manipulation should look like:

```js
function reshapeDivs(){
    var divs =  document.getElementsByClassName("someClass");
    for(i=0;i<divs.length;i++){
     divs[i].style.height = "200px";
     divs[i].style.marginTop = "30px"
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="someClass" style="border:1px solid red">blah1</div>
<div class="someClass"  style="border:1px solid black">blah2</div>
<button id="reshapeButton" onclick="reshapeDivs()">reshape divs</div>
```